# Proof for scalar product

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inner-products, trace

> Let $A,B \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$. Define $ \langle A,B \rangle := \operatorname{Tr}(A^*B)$.
>   Show that $\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle $ is a scalar product on $\mathbb{C}^{n\times
>  n}$.

I already proved the most properties. But I have trouble proving the homogeneity property.

Here is my solution:

$$\langle \lambda A,C \rangle = \operatorname{Tr}((\lambda A)^*C) =\operatorname{Tr}(\overline\lambda A^*C)=\overline\lambda \operatorname{Tr}(A^*C)=\overline\lambda \langle A,C\rangle.$$

But this is not the homogeneous property of complex scalar products, which is $ \langle \alpha x,y \rangle  = \alpha  \langle x,y \rangle$.

Can somebody tell me what did I do wrong?

P.S. The problem is from an old examine, so it can't be wrong.

Comment: If your scalar product shall be linear in the first argument, you have to define $\langle A, B \rangle = \operatorname{tr} (B^\ast A)$.

Answer (score 1):

This is just a difference of convention. The question assumes you want the *second* argument to be linear. (To change which argument is linear, just conjugate the inner product.) That's what physicists usually assume for quantum mechanics.